# POST request from Ember js (Ember-cli) to Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, ember.js

This is the JSON format that I get from Ember js when I make a POST request. I use RestAdapter to make an API call.

```
`{
   "programmer": {
      "firstName": "Janaki",
      "lastName": "Rathinam"
    }
 }`
```

But my spring boot would accept only

```
{
    "Programmer": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "Maha",
      "lastName": "Shankar"
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this mismatching JSONs so that I can make a POST call from emberjs.
Will adding Serializer resolve my issue? If yes how do I write a serializer for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use payloadKeyFromModelName to override the root key for an outgoing request. By default, the RESTSerializer returns a camelized version of the model's name.

For a model called Programmer, its modelName would be the string `programmer`. The RESTSerializer will send it to the server with `programmer` as the root key in the JSON payload:

```
{
   "programmer": {
      "firstName": "Janaki",
      "lastName": "Rathinam"
    }
 }
```

In your case you may expect **capitalized** root objects:

first run `$ ember generate serializer application` and then include the following:

app/serializers/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { capitalized } from '@ember/string';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  payloadKeyFromModelName(modelName) {
    return capitalized(modelName);
  }
});
```

The result would then be a root with capital P:

```
{
   "Programmer": {
      "firstName": "Janaki",
      "lastName": "Rathinam"
    }
 }
```

Ember Documentation: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.4/classes/DS.RESTSerializer/methods/payloadKeyFromModelName?anchor=payloadKeyFromModelName